# How do I remove the year and month from a DatetimeIndex in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.DataFrame(["2017-01-01 00:00:41","2017-01-01 00:06:53",\
                   "2017-01-01 00:07:10"],columns=["DateTime"])
df = pd.DataFrame([221,676,356],columns=["Value"])
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(idx["DateTime"])
df
```

which produces something like

```
      DateTime         Value
2017-01-01 00:13:41     221
2017-01-02 00:06:53     676
2017-01-05 00:22:10     356
```

What I would like to do next is remove the year and month information from this DateTime index, so as to produce

```
  DateTime     Value
01 00:13:41     221
02 00:06:53     676
05 00:22:10     356
```

I know that in the DataFrame idx I can drop it as follows:

```
idx["DateTime"] = idx["DateTime"].str(8:)
```

The problem is that this is no longer recognised by pandas as a DatetimeIndex. Moreover plotting this becomes very tricky (something I'd like to do subsequently). Any ideas how I can achieve this? (I'm sure it can be done, Python/pandas are too versatile not to have some cunning trick for achieving it!)

Comment: you can format your axis when you plot

Comment: True. But I deeply suspect there must be a neat python/pandas approach to achieving it. Formatting axes feels comparatively ugly.

Comment: @Stromael Curious if you every found a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the time, this would be what you are looking for

```
df.index = df.index.time

>>>df
          Value
00:00:41    221
00:06:53    676
00:07:10    356

>>>type(df.index[0])
datetime.time
```

---

As far as I can tell, the two possible objects are `time` objects and `datetime` objects, which means either way, you would need something for the year...

You could try to just standardize the year across them all like this:

```
df.index = [pd.datetime.strptime(s, '%d %HH-%MM-%SS') 
               for s in [pd.datetime.strftime(values, "%d %HH-%MM-%SS") 
               for values in df.index]]
```

(Just a first attempt... maybe a simpler way to accomplish this...)

Comment: I tried `df.index.time`, but it leaves me without the day information. I want the output index to have the form DD HH:MM:SS.

Comment: @Stephen Try plotting something with several days. This will cause overlapping plots.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Just realized you were looking for day _and_ time. But leaving off the year.... hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (updated)

df

```
                    Datetime  Values
0 2018-10-31 21:24:08.380554     258
1 2018-10-31 21:24:09.002616     586

df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, "%d %H:%M:%S"))

      Datetime  Values
0  31 21:24:08     258
1  31 21:24:09     586
```

Comment: This is not showing dates when plotting the dataframe.

Comment: Converts to strings which is the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
print (df['DateTime'].dt.day).astype(str) +' '+ (df['DateTime'].dt.time).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
0    1 00:13:41
1    2 00:06:53
2    5 00:22:10
Name: DateTime, dtype: object
```